# How am I supposed to initialize this?

Tags: c++

I have an object in my class that only has one constructor, and this constructor takes a pointer to an interface implemented by my class. So I want to put it on the initializer list:

```
: thatObject(this)
```

But that gives me a warning and I can understand why giving a pointer to an unconstructed class is not a good idea. So the question is, what do I do? Should I do:

```
: thatObject(NULL)
{
   thatObject = TheClass(this);
}
```

What is the proper way of dealing with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `thatObject` is guaranteed to never dereference the given pointer until after it's constructor is complete, then ignore or suppress the warning.  If you don't feel safe guaranteeing that it will never in the future dereference the pointer, than go with the second option.

In MSVC the code to supress a warning is:

```
#pragma warning(supress:4355)
: thatObject(this)
```

GCC is more complicated: (and untested, I don't have GCC)

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Winit-self"
: thatObject(this)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not a good idea to have a pointer to child in the father class. If you need to use that pointer to obtain some information or do something, write a virtual function in father, implement in child and call that.

If you really really have to do that, the method you suggested yourself works fine:

```
: thatObject(NULL)
{
   thatObject = TheClass(this);
}
```